# CsQuery pseudoselector exception

Tags: csquery

I started to have some exceptions where using the pseudoselector :first. This started to happen when I changed my target framework from 4 to 4.5.1 on visual studio. The same code was run before without any errors. Everything else with CsQuery seems to keep working fine.

On my project references I have CsQuery.1.3.5.124, I guess it could be a bug, not sure. It worked fine before.

any help?

Thanks.

There

```
Stack trace:

[ArgumentException: The key already existed in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +10940468
   CsQuery.Engine.PseudoSelectors.PopulateFromAssembly(Assembly assy, String[] nameSpaces) +344
   CsQuery.Engine.PseudoSelectors.Register(Assembly assembly) +153
   CsQuery.Engine.PseudoSelectors.PopulateInnerSelectors() +305
   CsQuery.Engine.PseudoSelectors..ctor() +168
   CsQuery.Engine.PseudoSelectors..cctor() +44

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CsQuery.Engine.PseudoSelectors' threw an exception.]
   CsQuery.Engine.PseudoSelectors.get_Items() +0
   CsQuery.Engine.SelectorParser.AddPseudoSelector(String key) +49
   CsQuery.Engine.SelectorParser.Parse(String selector) +2360
   CsQuery.Engine.Selector..ctor(String selector) +103
   CsQuery.CQ.Select(String selector) +83
   CsQuery.CQ.get_Item(String selector) +42
```

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 1):

This should only happen if there are custom pseudoselectors in your project, and further two of them with the same name. If you are just using straight CsQuery then I can't think why this would happen.

When CsQuery starts, by default, it will scan the calling assembly for classes that implement `IPseudoSelector` and attempt to register it. You can disable the automatic scanning for custom pseudoselectors with this (before running any selectors):

```
CsQuery.Config.StartupOptions = 0;
```

If you are actually using custom pseudoselectors you can register them manually as well, see this blog post for details:

```
http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/07/csquery-113-released.html
```

I can't think of any reason why changing frameworks would cause this to happen, so maybe it's just a coincidence, but hopefully this will give you the information you need to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have a custom pseudoselector implemented. The problem seems to be fixed now.

The problem was happening on a project that references another project where the pseudoselector is defined. Both project had references to CSQuery but different versions. I replaced the older version (in the project where the pseudoselector is defined) with the newest same version I have in the project where the problem is taking place.

Now it seems everything is back ok.

Thanks for your help!!